# Update IIS hosted WCF Service automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have WCF application server hosted in Local IIS, WCF server communicates with my client application resides in another PC. I Want to update WCF application Server and client application when user Clicks on update button.

When user click on Update button Client Call WCF service and check for updates. Dll and other File Version verification code already done. WCF Service also updating client application form the letest files but i don`t how do i update my Server application.

**Note :** Server Check for Update form internet.

Please Help if anyone know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i don`t how do i update my Server application

Copy up the new service binaries, overwrite the old ones, and bounce IIS.

If you want this to happen automatically use powershell.